# Continuous but nowhere differentiable function on domain

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I am trying to come up with an example of a function which is continuous on $[0,1]$ but nowhere differentiable but which is in a way simpler than Weierstrass function or "more intuitive" so to speak.

Do you know any such example?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this thesis: https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1022983/FULLTEXT01.pdf. Lots of examples.